Cannot upgrade aws sdk version for android app
I am trying to upgrade the underlying aws kotlin sdk version which I found to be out of date by logging Cognito authentication data. The version that is reported is aws-sdk-kotlin-0.17.12-beta which is around two years out of date. I have tried updating dependencies but the underlying version remains the same. I currently have the com.amplifyframework:aws auth-cognito, storage and api dependencies alongside the amazonaws:aws-android-sdk -core and -lambda dependencies. I have run a search for occurences of the underlying version within the project and five occurences came up in read only files with one of them being DefaultCognitoIdentityClient.kt
I tried updating the dependencies and updating the Amplify CLI but neither has resolved the underlying version
Edit - I have done some testing and I have found that three of the dependencies were not in use, the remaining AWS dependencies are implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-auth-cognito:2.2.0' and implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.77.0'

Could you try upgrading your aws-auth-cognito dependency to version 2.21.2?
You can find the latest version on the official release page.
For S3 and Lambda, the latest version is 1.3.24. You can include them in your project with:
implementation "aws.sdk.kotlin:s3:1.3.24"
implementation "aws.sdk.kotlin:lambda:1.3.24"

Let me know if this helps!

The version in the AWS Github example repo is 1.2.28.
See:
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/kotlin/services/comprehend/build.gradle.kts
Where are you getting a beta version from?
Also - you can directly use the AWS SDK for Kotlin within an ANdroid Studio project to invoke AWS Services without using Ampify.
